# Singularity structure of a multivalued function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-cuts, multivalued-functions, branch-points

Consider the function
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z} \ln \left( \frac{1-z}{1+z} \right).$$
This is clearly multivalued. There has to be two branch points at $\pm1$. Are there any other singularities, such as poles arising from the factor of $1/z$ or $\infty$? Does it depend on the choice of branch cuts?

For a simpler function such as $\ln(z)$, I know that there are branch points at $z=0$ and  $z=\infty$. A cut can be chosen to use multiple copies of the complex plane in order to define a single valued analytic function. Can someone please help me do such a construction for $f$?

Comment: The function $f(z)$ has a removeable discontinuity at $z=0$ that, once removed, renders  $f(z)$ analytic on the open unit disk.

Comment: i can see that on expanding $\ln(1\pm z)$, the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the series is zero. but if I chose the branch cut along the line joining $-1$ and $1$ along the real axis, does it even make sense to ask if $0$ is a regular or singular point? 
Edit: typo

Comment: If one chooses the branch cut to be from $-1$ to $1$, then $z=0$ is not in the domain.  It is certainly not a pole since $zf(z)$ is not holomorphic in any neighborhood of $0$.